# Hijack a CKeditor input field

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to be able to grab the onfocus event from the URL text input field when someone pulls up the Image dialog box in CKeditor.

I tried adding an event handler for the  element (id #cke_75_textInput) but it's only in the DOM after the Image button has been clicked.

Having looked through the CKEditor 3 JavaScript API Documentation and here, I was struggling and couldn't find what I needed.

Is this something that can be done through the API?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using jQuery, would you? It could help with binding the event with delegation. Basic JavaScript will have more of a problem because of bubbling issues with the `focus` event

Comment: Have a look at [this little article on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/04/delegating_the.html) about capturing the `focus`, `change`, and other non-bubbling events. Unless you can use jQuery, this would be my suggestion.

Comment: I am using jQuery. How does that make it easier?

Comment: I think delegated events. Let me try that...

Comment: @Galadai With jQuery, it's a lot easier. I just updated my answer to include a jQuery solution, and a demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to do some magic with focus delegation (which is a mess since focus does not bubble). Just use the CKEditor API:

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( evt ) {
    if ( evt.data.name == 'image' ) {
        var def = evt.data.definition;

        var onShow = def.onShow;
        def.onShow = function() {
            onShow && onShow.apply( this, arguments );

            var input = this.getContentElement( 'info', 'txtUrl' );
            console.log( input.getValue() );
            input.on( 'focus', function() {
                console.log( 'focused' );
            } );
        };
    }
} );
```

PS. CKE4's docs are more handful than old CKE3's - http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog

Comment: This works brilliantly but it's going to take some work to see how you got to this from the documentation.

Comment: There's a [dialog API sample](http://ckeditor.com/latest/samples/plugins/dialog/dialog.html) in every CKEditor package, [sample plugin guide](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1) and API docs I linked in my answer. It requires some time to compile all this, but all this is in official documentation. The only tricky part in my answer is how to get dialog instance. I overwrote `onShow` method of the dialog definition, but I think that simpler solution may (or should) exist.